# Unable to Connect to Bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth

This is the piece of code from Standard from Google sample code BluetoothChat.
BluetoothChatService.java

```
public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (mState == STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

As soon as I try to connect the device using

```
mChatService.connect(device, false);
```

I get following exception

```
java.io.IOException: bt socket closed, read return: -1
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:872)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.read(BluetoothInputStream.java:96)
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to the log , the bt connection attempt failed. So you can try system bluetooth to connect your device. Does the device need to be paired ?

Comment: The device is already paired.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include in android manifest Bluetooth permission for your app?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Comment: Yes . I have already included the above permissions in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is the `mmSocket.connect()`

Try to get the method `createRfcommSocket` by reflect.

Here is an example base on Google sample code BluetoothChat.

```
            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
                OutputStream os = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
                // Here: connect success
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Lost 1st try; SPP connect[2]");
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();// close the current socket
                    mmSocket = null;
                    Thread.sleep(500L); // wait for a while
                    mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class}).invoke(mmDevice, 1); // The key method !
                    mmSocket.connect();
                    OutputStream os = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
                    // Here: connect success
                    synchronized (ESDevice.this) {
                        mSPPConnectThread = null;
                    }
                    connected(mmSocket, mmDevice); // begin connected thread
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Lost 2nd try. Connect fail", e2);
                    connectionFailed();
                    return;
                }
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like socket was closed before you passed it in your `mConnectedThread`'s constructor.

There is one tricky thing in Google sample, in `mConnectThread` when socket was actually connected we make mConnectThread null, and next code won't be executed:

```
if (mConnectThread != null) {
    mConnectThread.cancel();
    mConnectThread = null;
}
```

that means that `cancel()` method which closes the socket will be skipped.

Basically, make sure you don't call `close()` method in `ConnectThread` after your socket was connected.